# AngularJS: `{{ x + ', ' + y }}` vs. `{{ x }}, {{ y }}`

Tags: angularjs

Does `{{ x + ', ' + y }}` make any difference to `{{ x }}, {{ y }}`?

Especially in the aspect of watcher's cost?

I'm wondering if I can reduce the number of digest loops by combining two-way binding curly braces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to benchmark it. The number of digest cycles doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One digest loop would handle one or both of them if it's going to do it at all; it won't be a digest for `x` and then another for `y` (unless you trigger a new one later). Technically, I'd say the former one is slightly more taxing because it involves string concatenation, but I suspect this has to happen at some point behind the scenes with the latter version anyway.

Overall, I don't expect you'll get a noticeable performance difference with this level of expression unless you're displaying hundreds or thousands of them at once (in which case, you'll probably have other problems as well and should rethink your approach).

Answer (score 2):

The `{{}}` notation is slower than using the `ng-bind` directive :

The `{{}}` will be dirty checked at every digest cycle whereas `ng-bind` places a watcher on the value passed in parameter and will update it only when it has changed.
Another advantage of using `ng-bind` over `{{}}` is that the user won't see the `{{}}` in the page when angular is still loading.

Additionally you can use the new `::` notation (introduced in angular 1.3) for static binding (when you know your variable won't change) :

```
<h1 data-ng-bind="::title"></h1>
```

About the references for the `{{}}` vs `ng-bind` notations :

- [benchmark](https://ng-perf.com/2014/10/30/tip-4-ng-bind-is-faster-than-expression-bind-and-one-time-bind/)
- [Someone quoting Igor Minar](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide/issues/41) (one of the developer of AngularJS):

> "ng-bind is faster because it’s simpler. interpolation has to go
>   through extra steps of verifying context, jsonification of values and
>   more. that makes it slightly slower."

Comment: Is there any reference on the performance about `ng-bind x {{}}` ? I'd like to explore more about it

Comment: Added some references

Comment: The original quote is from the first link ^^ The methodology of the benchmark is ... not ideal and the quote continues with _"in most cases the difference does not matter"_. As for dirty checking: There's no difference between the two.

Comment: Many thanks for introducing static binding. Didn't know that before. Now I've replaced lots of variables to `::` notation. Works so great!

Answer (score 1):

TO be precise the first expression will produces one watch but angular will recompute the concatenation.

On the second line you may think there will be 2 watch but it may be not (i'm not sure). I know that if you do this :

```
<span> blabla {{x}} blabla</span>
```

Angular will watch the whole content of the span. So if you have multiple usage of brackets you will very likely have only one watch for the whole thing.